# Микросервис на Python

Tags: python, rest, микросервисы

Нашел одну [библиотеку](https://relatorio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) на Python и она оказалась очень простой и удобной для формирования документов по шаблонам, а теперь для подключения к своим проектам нужно сделать на ее основе микросервис и вытащить наружу несколько REST-запросов для взаимодействия (даже не обязательно web-интерфейс прикручивать, но в дальнейшем было бы вообще замечательно). Вопрос, за какие инструменты браться и куда смотреть, чтобы это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Микросервисы проще всего делать на Flask. Минимальный пример из документации, веб-сервис, который говорит "Hello, World!":

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Функционал там тоже несложно прикручивать, буквально в пару строк всё делается.
[Документация Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)